# Product reviews tab on product page cuts off on mobile display. Woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

the thing is that when I open the product review tab in every product page on my online store (made with Wordpress), it cuts off, the text cuts and it look very bad. Let me show you a screenshot https://ibb.co/3sccFgj . As you can see, the text cuts off on the right side, I have to say that when the phone mode is on horizontal mode, it doesn't cut off, so this only happens on vertical display.I will be very grateful if you could help me here, maybe with some CSS coding. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be ignored when the user click (tap) on the textbox, that way the "screen" will move to center that element.

Before. https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8cyI.jpg

After tapping.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5db3.jpg

But you can also try to remove the element

```
.woocommerce #reviews {
    display: flex;
}
```

That way the comment section will appear below the other coments, not at the right side.

This is how it looks for me.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I put the: .woocommerce #reviews {
    display: flex;
}                                                                                                                                                    in CSS but it didn't work, are you sure that you didn't miss a letter or something? Thanks very much for replying anyways

Comment: And where can I find that element? On theme editor?

Comment: Yes or also there should be a css file.

Comment: You are literally THE MAN bro, thanks very much, I finally fix the issue. I must confess that I am very newbie at this programming world (I am creating my website with tutorials on Youtube so you may get an idea), so having this type of forums and awesome people like you is very useful. Greetings from Mexico

Comment: @Guerel10 Glad it worked. also If my post works for you, please consider marking my post as an answer. Thank you.